# Connections not reused with Jersey, ApacheConnectorProvider and PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x, jersey-client

We're using **Jersey** with **ApacheConnectorProvider** and **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** for pooled connections management.

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, defaultConnectTimeout);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, defaultReadTimeout);
        
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(50);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, cm);

clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
```

The issue is that the **connections are not reused**.
When getting Response and reading the entity using *response.readEntity()*, then the connection is closed and removed from the pool.

On *response.readEntity()* the below close action is happening:

```
ConnectionHolder.close()  -> 
 ConnectionHolder.releaseConnection(reusable=false)
```

The *releaseConnection()* is invoked using **reusable=false** which causing the issue.

We're using Jersey 2.22.2 and I tried it with multiple httpclient - 4.5, 4.5.2, 4.5.12, for all of them there is pretty much the same issue.

Is there some other configuration or am I missing something? because it seems like a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was fixed in Jersey 2.29 as you can see here:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4024

As we're using Payara server with **Jersey 2.22.2**, I cannot update Jersey's version to 2.29, but the fix includes only in one file, **ApacheConnector**, which is part of *jersey-apache-connector*, and so I tried to update only *jersey-apache-connector* to 2.29, and it worked.

*jersey-apache-connector* is not build in in Payara so I can use whatever version I want.

In most of the cases it's not a good idea to have some Jersey artifacts using one version and other artifacts using different version, but otherwise we won't have reusable connections, and also I didn't found yet any compatibility issues with other Jersey 2.22.2 artifacts, hope there aren't.